# How use modal navigation drawer in compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I want to use modal navigation drawer, but I don't know if for each destination of modal navigation drawer I have to navigate to another composable, or just switch between states to change the content of the content parameter of modal navigation drawer.

I plan to put multiple navigation destinations in the modal navigation drawer.[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is better to have multiple components for each screen because you might want to follow Single Responsibility Principle of SOLID. In addition, if you want to use states then you would have to handle a lot of code in one ViewModel, which is not scalable and maintainable.